# Correlation of multiple time series among the same variables in R

Tags: r, time, correlation, series

I have around 150 time series from 2001 to 2020 with the same variables, each for a different location/city.

Now I am wondering how I can **check the correlations among the variables across those time series** in R, without losing the actual time series/development information.

I am sorry if I'm missing something obvious here, but I hope somebody can help.

---

To further explain:

I have data of 150 cities that looks like that:

| Year | Cityname | Population | Unemployed | Primary Education | Secondary Education | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | City1 | 150432 | 4352 | 95234 | 73874 |  |
| 2002 | City1 | 152221 | 4014 | 95914 | 73923 |  |
| 2003 | City1 | 153321 | 3726 | 96143 | 74219 |  |
| 2004 | City1 | 156212 | 3484 | 97356 | 75745 |  |
| 2005 | City1 | 156345 | 3965 | 97643 | 75949 |  |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |

| Year | Cityname | Population | Unemployed | Primary Education | Secondary Education | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | City2 | 67694 | 1958 | 42855 | 33243 |  |
| 2002 | City2 | 68499 | 1806 | 43161 | 33265 |  |
| 2003 | City2 | 68994 | 1677 | 43264 | 33399 |  |
| 2004 | City2 | 70295 | 1568 | 43810 | 34085 |  |
| 2005 | City2 | 70355 | 1784 | 43939 | 34177 |  |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |

On its own, the data of each city is not sufficient to reach significant conclusions as (1) it's only yearly (19 years) and (2) it's only valid for 1 city then.

However, I was hoping that if combined, I would be able to see some more solid correlations (for example, between Unemployed and Education among all cities). As the development itself can be very telling, I would like to use the times series information as well.

- Is there a way to check the overarching correlation between the
  variables among the different time series (i.e. to find out if there
  is a correlation between education and unemployment among all
  cities)?
- What would be the best approach here?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I used this link when I was trying to figure it out: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/correlation-matrix-a-quick-start-guide-to-analyze-format-and-visualize-a-correlation-matrix-using-r-software

Personally I liked the chart.correlation()

```
library("PerformanceAnalytics")
my_data <- mtcars[, c(1,3,4,5,6,7)]
chart.Correlation(my_data, histogram=TRUE, pch=19)
```

but Hmisc is also good

```
library("Hmisc")
res2 <- rcorr(as.matrix(my_data))
res2
```

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need to use the time (year) variable as a parameter, and thus ignore the time dimension for simple correlation.

(Using data from ale_ish's example):

```
my_data <- mtcars[, c(1,3,4,5,6,7)]
cor(my_data)

> cor(my_data)
            mpg       disp         hp        drat         wt        qsec
mpg   1.0000000 -0.8475514 -0.7761684  0.68117191 -0.8676594  0.41868403
disp -0.8475514  1.0000000  0.7909486 -0.71021393  0.8879799 -0.43369788
hp   -0.7761684  0.7909486  1.0000000 -0.44875912  0.6587479 -0.70822339
drat  0.6811719 -0.7102139 -0.4487591  1.00000000 -0.7124406  0.09120476
wt   -0.8676594  0.8879799  0.6587479 -0.71244065  1.0000000 -0.17471588
qsec  0.4186840 -0.4336979 -0.7082234  0.09120476 -0.1747159  1.00000000
```

As for time series analysis your best bet is to first plot out your data using the time variable for the x axis. Then you could do a simple [linear regression](https://rpubs.com/aprasar/lm_mtcars) for starters, and go from there.